# Php warning error

Tags: php

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /srv/disk2/*/www/*/admin.php:39) in /srv/disk2/*/www/*/admin.php on line 40

Comment: What is line 38/39 on `admin.php`? `session_start` should be the first line...

Comment: Please show more code

Comment: }</style>
<?php 
session_start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have any space and you MUST start session in the top! For example:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private');
```

**UPDATE:** Don't let blank space before `<?php`

Comment: Sorry, beat you to it! Also, that `header` line has nothing to do with it

Comment: <body>
<?php 
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private');
if($_SESSION["student_id"]=="testingid" && $_SESSION["password"]==base64_encode("testingpassword")){
 if($_GET["p"]=="SDADSDSADSADSBKVCCKNMSMKDnaksndkjNJKNjknjKNJKnKJN"){
  session_destroy();
   header("LOCATION: index.php?STUDENTLOGIN");
  }
 ?>

Comment: Still getting Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /srv/disk2/1439229/www/thefastschool.co.nf/admin.php:8) in /srv/disk2/1439229/www/thefastschool.co.nf/admin.php on line 9

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk2/1439229/www/thefastschool.co.nf/admin.php:8) in /srv/disk2/1439229/www/thefastschool.co.nf/admin.php on line 10

Comment: Try to put ob_start(); on the top and after that session_start();

Comment: @ErmanBelegu: That has been suggested a lot (on different questions), and that only hides the errors!

Comment: @user2594603 I update the answer. Be SURE that you don't have space before php tag.

Answer (score 4):

`session_start()` **always** needs to be called before output is sent.

The first two lines of your document need to look like this:

```
<?php
session_start()
```

Try calling `session_start()` before any output!

More info on this function can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: +1, the scary part is if you're on shared hosting and they output something before you. Or even worse, [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)...